# How can you include a javascript files from a CDN in Jasmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jasmine

When using Jasmine in a Rails project, to keep the dependencies consistent in my Jasmine specs, I want to pull jquery from a cdn as is done on the real page.  I try to do that like so, in my Jasmine.yml file:

```
helpers:
  - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
```

However, this never works, as when viewing the source of the localhost:8888 I get:

```
<script src="/__spec__/http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How do you this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as answered in https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem/issues/135

I wrote a helper to load external javascripts. It's not the best solution (i would prefer config file use) but it works for me.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
jQueryScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js');
head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

@emrox's answer is correct and works for jasmine 2.0.

However in **jasmine 2.1.3** it doesn't. This is due to the fact that when the tests are run(i'm using Chutzpah) **"http:"** isn't pre-pended to the CDN reference. It is in version 2.0 of jasmine.

The fix I implemented that worked involved the following line of code:

> jQueryScript.setAttribute('src',
>   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js');

Hopefully this helps someone before they decide to downgrade to 2.0!

Answer (score 1):

Issue [135](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-gem/issues/135) made it so you can list CDN entries in your jasmine.yml file.  e.g.

```
src_files:
  - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js
  - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js
  - lib/javascript/**/*.js
```